# Javaslang - running a method in Pattern Matcher

Tags: java, java-8, vavr

I'm trying to incorporate javaslang's pattern matching in a classic factory pattern:

```
public void log(String message, Integer level) {
        Match(level).of(
                Case($(INFO), run(() -> logger.info(message))), //
                Case($(DEBUG), run(() -> logger.debug(message))), //
                Case($(WARNING), run(() -> logger.warn(message))), //
                Case($(ERROR), run(() -> logger.error(message))), //
                Case($(), run(() -> logger.info(message)))); 
}
```

Yet this spills and all the methods are run (I get four identical calls to different levels of the logger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not actually call `run`, you need some lazy evaluation. As i do not see a reason to call `run` at all, i just removed. This should work.

**Edit:**  added `run` to provide an inferable return value.

```
public void log(String message, Integer level) {
        Match(level).of(
                Case($(INFO), l -> run( () -> logger.info(message))), //
                Case($(DEBUG), l -> run( () -> logger.debug(message))), //
                Case($(WARNING), l -> run( () -> logger.warn(message))), //
                Case($(ERROR), l -> run( () -> logger.error(message))), //
                Case($(), l -> run( () -> logger.info(message)))); 
}
```

Comment: this gives a compilation error "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> of(API.Match.Case<? extends T,? extends R>[]" and "Cannot return a void result".

Comment: @fbielejec i made an adjustment, maybe it works now.